# Add values retrieved from Web Driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have written a Webdriver C# script that locates values on a page and converts these values to doubles.

There are three variables involved in my validation test: totalPrice, tax and totalBilled.

I would like to verify that the totalPrice + tax will equal the totalBilled amount.

Below is my code so far

```
       // Total Price Variables
        string totalPrice;
        string totalPriceTrm;
        double totalPriceDbl;

        // Tax Variables
        string tax;
        string taxTrm;
        double taxDbl;

        // Total Billed Variables
        string totalBilled;
        string totalBilledTrm;
        double totalBilledDbl;

        double totalBilledAmountToVerify;


        // Read in Total Price
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> aa = driver.FindElements(By.Id("total_price"));
        for (int k = 0; k < aa.Count; k++)
        {

            //Console.WriteLine("Order Number" + " " + ec[k].GetAttribute("value"));
            totalPrice = aa[k].GetAttribute("value");
            totalPriceTrm = totalPrice.Trim( new Char[] { ' ', 'A', 'U', 'D', '$'} );
            totalPriceDbl = Convert.ToDouble(totalPriceTrm);
        }

        // Read in Tax
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> bb = driver.FindElements(By.Id("gst"));
        for (int k = 0; k < bb.Count; k++)
        {

            //Console.WriteLine("Order Number" + " " + ec[k].GetAttribute("value"));
            tax = bb[k].GetAttribute("value");
            taxTrm = tax.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', 'A', 'U', 'D', '$' });
            taxDbl = Convert.ToDouble(taxTrm);
        }

        // Read in Total Billed
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> cc = driver.FindElements(By.Id("final_price"));
        for (int k = 0; k < cc.Count; k++)
        {

            //Console.WriteLine("Order Number" + " " + ec[k].GetAttribute("value"));
            totalBilled = cc[k].GetAttribute("value");
            totalBilledTrm = totalBilled.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', 'A', 'U', 'D', '$' });
            totalBilledDbl = Convert.ToDouble(totalBilledTrm);

        }
```

Problem: I have declared a double totalBilledAmountToVerify and would like it to store the result of totalPriceDbl + taxDbl. Then, I want to compare the totalBilledDbl with totalBilledAmountToVerify (both should be equal).

However, when I insert the following line, I get a message telling me that totalPriceDbl and taxDbl are unassigned. I think these variables need to be included in the scope but I am unsure how to do this.

totalBilledAmountToVerify = totalPriceDbl + taxDbl;

Comment: You should take a look at this guide [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

You assign values to the variables inside a `for` loop. It's possible that the code inside a loop will never execute (for example code inside `for (int k = 0; k < aa.Count; k++)` will not execute if `aa.Count` is 0). That's why you get the error that the variables might be unassigned.

To easily fix it, assign some values to the variables when you declare them

```
double taxDbl = 0;
double totalBilledDbl = 0;
```

Actually you don't even need the `for` loops. `FindElements(By.Id)` should only return a single element. If it doesn't, try to use css selector to get a single result.